# How to implement webRTC in firefox?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firefox, webrtc

This code works in google chrome fine ,
but i tried to convert it to support Firefox
and i always get no error in the console .
the cam it seems ruining but there's no video.
here's the script

```
  var socket = new WebSocket('ws://127.0.0.1:1338/');  // change the IP address to your websocket server
  var stunServer = "stun.l.google.com:19302";
  var sourcevid = document.getElementById('sourcevid');
  var remotevid = document.getElementById('remotevid');
  var localStream = null;
  var remoteStream;
  var peerConn = null;
  var started = false;
  var isRTCPeerConnection = true;
  var mediaConstraints = {mandatory: {
                            OfferToReceiveAudio:true, 
                            OfferToReceiveVideo:true }};

 var logg = function(s) { console.log(s); };



  // send the message to websocket server
  function sendMessage(message) {
      var mymsg = JSON.stringify(message);
      logg("SEND: " + mymsg);
      socket.send(mymsg);
  }

  function createPeerConnection() {
    try {
      logg("Creating peer connection");
      var servers = [];
      servers.push({'url':'stun:' + stunServer});
      var pc_config = {'iceServers':servers};     
      peerConn = new webkitRTCPeerConnection(pc_config);
      peerConn.onicecandidate = onIceCandidate;
    } catch (e) {
        try {
          peerConn = new RTCPeerConnection('STUN ' + stunServer, onIceCandidate00);
          isRTCPeerConnection = false;
        } catch (e) {
          logg("Failed to create PeerConnection, exception: " + e.message);
        }
    }

    peerConn.onaddstream = onRemoteStreamAdded;
    peerConn.onremovestream = onRemoteStreamRemoved;
  }

  // when remote adds a stream, hand it on to the local video element
  function onRemoteStreamAdded(event) {
    logg("Added remote stream");
    remotevid.src = window.webkitURL.createObjectURL(event.stream);
  }

   function waitForRemoteVideo() {
    if (remoteStream.videoTracks.length === 0 || remotevid.currentTime > 0) {
      transitionToActive();
    } else {
      setTimeout(waitForRemoteVideo, 100);
    }
  }

    function transitionToActive() {
    remotevid.style.opacity = 1;
    card.style.webkitTransform = "rotateY(180deg)";
    setTimeout(function() { sourcevid.src = ""; }, 500);
    setStatus("<input type=\"button\" id=\"hangup\" value=\"Hang up\" onclick=\"onHangup()\" />");
  }

  // when remote removes a stream, remove it from the local video element
  function onRemoteStreamRemoved(event) {
    logg("Remove remote stream");
    remotevid.src = "";
  }

  function onIceCandidate(event) {
    if (event.candidate) {
      sendMessage({type: 'candidate',
                   label: event.candidate.sdpMLineIndex,
                   id: event.candidate.sdpMid,
                   candidate: event.candidate.candidate});
    } else {
      logg("End of candidates.");
    }
  }

  function onIceCandidate00(candidate, moreToFollow) {
    if (candidate) {
        sendMessage({type: 'candidate', label: candidate.label, candidate: candidate.toSdp()});
    }
    if (!moreToFollow) {
      logg("End of candidates.");
    }
  }

  // start the connection upon user request
  function connect() {
    if (!started && localStream) {

      console.log("Creating PeerConnection.");
      createPeerConnection();
      logg('Adding local stream...');
      peerConn.addStream(localStream);
      started = true;
      logg("isRTCPeerConnection: " + isRTCPeerConnection);

      //create offer
      if (isRTCPeerConnection) {
        peerConn.createOffer(setLocalAndSendMessage, null, mediaConstraints);
      } else {
        var offer = peerConn.createOffer(mediaConstraints);
        peerConn.setLocalDescription(peerConn.SDP_OFFER, offer);
        sendMessage({type: 'offer', sdp: offer.toSdp()});
        peerConn.startIce();
      }

    } else {
      alert("Local stream not running yet.");
    }
  }

  // accept connection request
  socket.addEventListener("message", onMessage, false);
  function onMessage(evt) {
    logg("RECEIVED: " + evt.data);
    if (isRTCPeerConnection)
      processSignalingMessage(evt.data);
    else
      processSignalingMessage00(evt.data);
  }

  function processSignalingMessage(message) {
    var msg = JSON.parse(message);

    if (msg.type === 'offer') {

      if (!started && localStream) {
        createPeerConnection();
        logg('Adding local stream...');
        peerConn.addStream(localStream);
        started = true;
        logg("isRTCPeerConnection: " + isRTCPeerConnection);


        if (isRTCPeerConnection) {
          //set remote description
          peerConn.setRemoteDescription(new RTCSessionDescription(msg));
          //create answer
          console.log("Sending answer to peer.");
          peerConn.createAnswer(setLocalAndSendMessage, null, mediaConstraints);
        } else {
          //set remote description
          peerConn.setRemoteDescription(peerConn.SDP_OFFER, new SessionDescription(msg.sdp));
          //create answer
          var offer = peerConn.remoteDescription;
          var answer = peerConn.createAnswer(offer.toSdp(), mediaConstraints);
          console.log("Sending answer to peer.");
          setLocalAndSendMessage00(answer);
        }
      }

    } else if (msg.type === 'answer' && started) {
      peerConn.setRemoteDescription(new RTCSessionDescription(msg));
    } else if (msg.type === 'candidate' && started) {
      var candidate = new RTCIceCandidate({sdpMLineIndex:msg.label, candidate:msg.candidate});
      peerConn.addIceCandidate(candidate);
    } else if (msg.type == 'chat'){
        addChatMsg(msg.nick, msg.cid, msg.data);
    } 
    else if (msg.type === 'bye' && started) {
      onRemoteHangUp();
    }
  }

  function processSignalingMessage00(message) {
    var msg = JSON.parse(message);

    // if (msg.type === 'offer')  --> will never happened since isRTCPeerConnection=true initially
    if (msg.type === 'answer' && started) {
      peerConn.setRemoteDescription(peerConn.SDP_ANSWER, new SessionDescription(msg.sdp));
    } else if (msg.type === 'candidate' && started) {
      var candidate = new IceCandidate(msg.label, msg.candidate);
      peerConn.processIceMessage(candidate);
    } else if (msg.type === 'bye' && started) {
      onRemoteHangUp();
    }
  }

  function setLocalAndSendMessage(sessionDescription) {
    peerConn.setLocalDescription(sessionDescription);
    sendMessage(sessionDescription);
  }

  function setLocalAndSendMessage00(answer) {
    peerConn.setLocalDescription(peerConn.SDP_ANSWER, answer);
    sendMessage({type: 'answer', sdp: answer.toSdp()});
    peerConn.startIce();
  }

  function onRemoteHangUp() {
    logg("Remote Hang up.");
    closeSession();
  }

  function onHangUp() {
    logg("Hang up.");
    if (started) {
      sendMessage({type: 'bye'});
      closeSession();
    }
  }

  function closeSession() {
    peerConn.close();
    peerConn = null;
    started = false;
    remotevid.src = ""; 
  }

  window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    if (started) {
      sendMessage({type: 'bye'});
    }
  }

  function startVideo() {
      // Replace the source of the video element with the stream from the camera
      if (navigator.mozGetUserMedia) { 
      try { 
        navigator.mozGetUserMedia({audio: true, video: true}, successCallback, errorCallback);
      } catch (e) {
        navigator.mozGetUserMedia("video,audio", successCallback, errorCallback);
      }
      }
      else { 
      try { 
        navigator.webkitGetUserMedia({audio: true, video: true}, successCallback, errorCallback);
      } catch (e) {
        navigator.webkitGetUserMedia("video,audio", successCallback, errorCallback);
      }
      }
      function successCallback(stream) {
      if (navigator.mozGetUserMedia) { 
          sourcevid.mozSrcObject = stream;
          sourcevid.style.webkitTransform = "rotateY(180deg)";
          localStream = stream;
          }
      if(navigator.webkitGetUserMedia){
        sourcevid.src = window.webkitURL.createObjectURL(stream);
        sourcevid.style.webkitTransform = "rotateY(180deg)";
        localStream = stream;
    } 

      }
      function errorCallback(error) {
          logg('An error occurred: [CODE ' + error.code + ']');
      }
  }

  function stopVideo() {
    sourcevid.src = "";
  }
```

and here is the html

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('bundles/PFESiivt/js/visio.js') }}"></script>

<div id="main">
    <div id="" style="height:280px;width:700;">
        <div id="livevideodivk" style="float:left;">
            <video id="sourcevid" style="height:280px;width:320px;" autoplay></video>
        </div>

        <div id="remotevideodivk" style="float:left;margin-left:10px">
            <video id="remotevid" style="height:280px;width:320px;" autoplay></video>
        </div>
    </div>
    <center>
        <button id="btn" type="button" onclick="startVideo();">Start video</button>
        <button id="btn" type="button" onclick="stopVideo();">Stop video</button>
        <button id="btn" type="button" onclick="connect();">Connect</button>
        <button id="btn" type="button" onclick="onHangUp();">Hang Up</button>
    </center>


</div>
```

Comment: Firefox is not webkit-based, so none of the `webkit`-prefixed functions here will work. Have you considered using [adapter.js](https://github.com/webrtc/adapter) the cross-browser polyfill for WebRTC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have not gone through the complete code, but for starters...

- for firefox it is `mozRTCPeerConnection` not `RTCPeerConnection`.
- secondly, for firefox `PeerConnection` object, the `onicecandidate` handler is missing.

**P. S:** I think it is a very bad idea to post complete code, would advice to do bit of debugging yourself( to identify the block causing issue) and then post the relevant block when not able to solve it.

Comment: similar issue with `onRemoteStreamAdded` and `webkitURL`.